# measuring time of signal

Tags: c, signals

I need to measure the time it takes to handle an exception and invoke a signal handler 100,000 times. I need to use `signal()`system call to register a handler function for `SIGFPE` then i need to cause a divide by 0 error.

I only have a skeleton right now and am not sure how I should handle the signal. So far I plan on calling `gettimeofday()` then entering in a for loop 100k times to invoke the `signal()` then another `gettimeofday()` in order to end the time and then take the total elapsed time and average it out over those 100k invocations.

```
#include <signal.h>
#include <sys/time.h>

void handle_sigfe(int signum)
{ 
 //unsure how to handle the signal to keep the loop running for 100k times 

}

double time_in_milli (struct timeval t){ //for time conversion
return (((t.tv_sec*1000000+t.tv_usec)*1000)/1000000);
}

int main(int argv, char ** argv)
{
int x =5;
int y = 0;
int z = 0;
signal(SIGFPE, handle_sigfpe);
z = x/y;

return 0;
}
```

Anyone have any clue on how I need to handle this signal? I am completely lost on this

Comment: Look at `setjmp` and `siglongjmp` - you'll need those to safely recover from the divide-by-zero error.

Comment: @nneonneo I just read up on them via man page and they still confuse me, I'm not sure how I would use them in order to keep going through the loop.

Comment: @nneonneo do you know how I could use those in order to bypass the `exit` so I can invoke it 100k times to keep track of a total time then use that to find the average? I know I need a for loop to be able to keep track of how many times but I am not sure how to stop the signal from causing it to crash

Comment: `siglongjmp` back into your `for` loop, I guess. Or ask your prof if this is some kind of homework (I'd be mildly surprised if you had to learn setjmp in C at this stage, but I don't know what kind of class you're taking).

Comment: @nneonneo im not sure how to use `siglongjmp` and its a OS class, if in my signalhandler I called `gettimeofday()` then went into my for loop and then used `siglongjmp` to keep going back to the for loop and at the completion of the loop called `gettimeofday()` then used those 2 times to get the data I need. Does this logic make sense? Also can you possibly give an example of how I could use `siglongjmp` i didn't understand the different info I read online

Comment: OK, wow, integer division by zero causes a SIGFPE, but floating point division by zero doesn't cause a SIGFPE. Learn something new every day. I'm going to delete all of my comments. Appreciate it if you delete all of your comments directed to me. Then I'll answer the question. Thanks.

Comment: @user3386109 sure no problem, appreciate the help and glad you were able to learn something new hopefully I can too haha

Comment: I guess you guys are thinking way too complicated. Make x and y global and assign values `x = y = 1` avoiding SIGFPE when returning from the signal handler. No need for `siglongjmp()` for this task.

Comment: @tofro The point of the exercise is to understand how signals work. To keep it simple, just check `if(y==0)` before doing the division. Then you don't need the signal handler at all.

Comment: @user3386109 From the Linux `siglongjmp`manual page: *longjmp() and siglongjmp() make programs hard to understand and maintain. If possible an alternative should be used.* - I go with them. It's not needed here for the task of measuring signal latency and not needed to get to understand signals (And maybe not needed in the other 99% of the rare cases it's used).

Comment: @tofro An equally valid phrasing of your quote: *"global variables make programs hard to understand and maintain. If possible an alternative should be used"*.

Answer (score 0):

A divide-by-zero exception invokes the handler that you installed. When the handler returns, the processor goes back to the division instruction and tries again. The result is an infinite loop. To prevent that, you can use the `sigsetjmp` and `siglongjmp` routines.

When you call `sigsetjmp` it returns 0. However, when `siglongjmp` is called, the program behaves as if `sigsetjmp` returns the value supplied by `siglongjmp`. So you can use an `if` statement to execute the division or skip the division based on the return value from `sigsetjmp`.

If that's too confusing, hopefully the following example will clear things up.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <setjmp.h>

static sig_atomic_t caught = 33;
static sigjmp_buf env;

void action( int unused )
{
    caught = 42;
    siglongjmp( env, 1 );
}

int main( void )
{
    if ( signal( SIGFPE, action ) == SIG_ERR ) {
        perror( "signal failed" );
        return 1;
    }

    int x = 1;
    int y = 0;
    int z;
    if ( sigsetjmp( env, 1 ) == 0 )
        z = x / y;

    printf( "%d\n", caught );
}
```

The global variable `caught` is used to indicate that the exception was caught. The initial value is 33. The signal handler sets it to 42. The `printf` at the end of the program displays the final value. It should print 42 to indicate the that signal was caught.

The global variable `env` is used by the `sigsetjmp` and `siglongjmp` functions to save a copy of the registers and stack.

The `if (sigsetjmp(env,1) == 0)` will initially be true, and the division will be attempted. But when the handler is invoked, `siglongjmp` will make the program behave as if `sigsetjmp` returned `1`, and the division will be skipped.

This allows the program to move past the division, and execute the `printf` at the end.

Comment: are the values of `33` or `42` needed or are those just random numbers? Also the design I am trying to understand would be to invoke the signal handler 100k times and use `gettimeofday()` to measure the elapsed time for the process. Does the `signal()` function register a handler function for `SIGFPE` ? I think I need to invoke my handler 100k times then at the end of the program cause a divide by zero exception

Comment: Seems like `sig_atomic_t` for `caught` would be more appropriate. Even though `SIGFPE` is a synchronous signal, it is generally a good idea to get into the habit of only using atomic variables.

Comment: The values 33 and 42 are random, chosen to be distinctive. You don't need the `caught` variable in your program. It's only there because one is not supposed to call `printf` from within a handler.

Comment: @nneonneo True, if optimizations were enabled and/or the signal was asynchronous. However, if optimizations are enabled, then I would expect the division will be optimized out. Agreed that it's a good habit to get into.

Comment: @bkennedy To invoke the hander 100K times, you would put the `if(sigsetjmp,...)` inside of a `for` loop. You can also use the `caught` variable as a counter, to prove that you actually caught the signal 100K times.

Comment: @user3386109 so `siglongjmp (env , 1)` causes the line `z = x/y` to be skipped? for my purposes I think my logic would be to `loop` over the `signal()` call and use a variable to keep track of the invocations and up in the handler `if else` statement so if invocations = 100k it wont run, else it will jump back down and repeat until it is 100k. At the termination of this it would cause the error and crash my program. Does this make sense? Also since I need to measure time should I use the `gettimeofday()` in the signal handler or before I invoke the first `signal()` call and then bfor div by 0?

Comment: @bkennedy Yes, the `siglongjmp` skips the division. So you could increment a counter in the handler and only call `siglongjmp` when the counter reaches 100K. If that's what you decide to do, then call `gettimeofday` before and after the `if` statement.

Comment: @user3386109 the `if` in the handler where it checks counter to be under 100k or `if (sigsetjmp (env, 1) == 0)`?

Comment: The code in the handler should just increment the counter and call `siglongjmp` when ready. All of the timing stuff should be in `main`.

Comment: @user3386109 I have an infinite loop and I am not sure where I went wrong here, it seems as if the code to cause the divide by 0 is not even causing it to crash despite running it over and over

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124086/discussion-between-bkennedy-and-user3386109).

Comment: @bkennedy It may be time to start a new question, showing your current code. It's possible that your system removes the handler after invoking it, in which case the handler needs to call `signal` to re-install itself. On my system, the handler remains active until explicitly removed (which is why I didn't call `signal` inside the handler).

Comment: `siglongjmp`is overkill for this task - in the signal handler, simply assign values to x and y that will not lead to DivByZ when returning. x and y obviously need to be made global for that.